# Converting UIImageView Touch Coordinates to UIImage Coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm able to determine the coordinates of a touch event on a UIImageView. I need to then convert these coordinates to the coordinates of the image being displayed - which should be different, since my image is much larger than the UIImageView and I'm scaling the image with AspectFit.

What's the best way to determine the image coordinates of a touch event given the view coordinates of a UIImageView?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this should get you going.

```
CGPoint imageViewPoint = [touch locationInView:imageView];

float percentX = imageViewPoint.x / imageView.frame.size.width;
float percentY = imageViewPoint.y / imageView.frame.size.height;

CGPoint imagePoint = CGPointMake(image.size.width * percentX, image.size.height * percentY);
```

Assuming the `UIImageView` is called `imageView` the `UITouch` is called `touch` and the `UIImage` is called `image`.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: what if UIImage is not perfectly fit in UIImageView and there exist some space between UIImage. How can I get the right point on the UIImage?

Comment: @Boyi you would have to account for that in your calculation. However, I don't know how that would be possible. You'd have to look at the content mode and the size of the image to work out where the image is inside the image view. Easier just to make the image view fit at the correct aspect ratio using auto layout.

Comment: What if I need to get touch point after zooming imageView then what is the role of ScrollView ContentOffset and ZoomScale in this calculation? Pls Help

Comment: @boyi, you can use AVMakeRect from AVFoundation to calculate the image frame inside the ImageView, when the contentMode is AspectFit (which I think it is what you are using, from your comment). From there, subtract the origins and width differences when calculating the percentX/Y.

Comment: @AvineetGupta Are you able to find points in UIImage when image is zoomed and rotated ? , Because if image rotated (trasnform) frame is unused

Comment: Perfect answer. Thumbs up!!