# Converting UIImageView Touch Coordinates to UIImage Coordinates Aspect Fill

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have implemented this code in my App

[Converting UIImageView Touch Coordinates to UIImage Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200191/converting-uiimageview-touch-coordinates-to-uiimage-coordinates)

This code works like a charm, but I'm trying to do the same but with Aspect Fill, as far as I understand de code will not work because if the Image is smaller will scale bigger so I'm not seeing part of the image in those cases where the aspect ratio is not the same as Image.

This is the code I'm implementing:

```
private func pointConversion(point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

    if let image = self.imageView.image {
        let percentX = point.x / self.imageView.frame.size.width
        let percentY = point.y / self.imageView.frame.size.height
        return CGPoint(x: image.size.width * percentX , y: image.size.height * percentY)
    }
    return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me in a situation where the the image that is aspect-filling the view is smaller than the view in at least one dimension. Not sure it's encountered tests where both image dimensions are greater than the destination view's:

```
func mapPointThroughAspectFill(uiViewPoint:CGPoint)->CGPoint
// Maps a point from the coordinate space of our UIView into the space of the image
// which AspectFills that UIView
{
    let imageWidth = imageView!.image!.size.width
    let imageHeight = imageView!.image!.size.height
    let xScale = imageView!.bounds.size.width / imageWidth
    let yScale = imageView!.bounds.size.height / imageHeight
    var x, y,  o:CGFloat

    if (xScale>yScale) {
        // scale vertically from the center for height-pegged images
        o = (imageView.bounds.size.height - (imageHeight*xScale))/2;
        x = uiViewPoint.x / xScale;
        y = (uiViewPoint.y-o) / xScale;
    } else {
        // scale horizontally from the center for width-pegged images
        o = (imageView.bounds.size.width - (imageWidth*yScale))/2;
        x = (uiViewPoint.x-o) / yScale;
        y = uiViewPoint.y / yScale;
    }
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
```